# Error: jakarta.jms.JMSException: 'void org.apache.qpid.proton.engine. Transport.setOutboundFrameSizeLimit(int)

Tags: jms, qpid

I am trying to post a message to Amazon ActiveMQ broker using SoapUI 5.7.2 and Groovy script. Java 17 is installed on the machine.

Below is the code:

```java
import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import jakarta.jms.Connection;
import jakarta.jms.DeliveryMode;
import jakarta.jms.MessageProducer;
import jakarta.jms.Session;
import jakarta.jms.TextMessage;
import jakarta.jms.Topic;

JmsConnectionFactory factory = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqps://broker-url:5671");
factory.setUsername("username");
factory.setPassword("password");

Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

Getting an error:

```
jakarta.jms.JMSException: 'void org.apache.qpid.proton.engine. Transport.setOutboundFrameSizeLimit(int)' error at Connection connection = factory.createConnection()
```

Following jars are added:

- proton-j-0.34.1.jar
- qpid-jms-client-2.5.0.jar
- jakarta.jms-api-3.1.0.jar

Could someone please guide as what might be the cause of this error and how this can be fixed? Do we need to pass any other parameters with the url?

Comment: @JustinBertram Replaced jar with proton-j-0.34.1.jar but still getting the same error

Comment: Does this code work when you run it in a normal Java application (i.e. not in Groovy in SoapUI)?

Comment: What is the full stack trace and error message thrown?

Comment: @JustinBertram There were some old proton jars as well in lib folder. I removed the old versions of jar and now getting "jakarta.jms.JMSException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException" at the same line. 
The code does work using a normal java application and simply using jakarta jms and qpid jms libraries

Comment: If the code works from a standard Java application with only the required jars in the classpath that suggests there's something on your classpath in SoapUI that's causing a problem.

Comment: Since the error has changed due to changes in your operating environment I strongly recommend you update your question to reflect the current status. Otherwise you're going to get answers to your old question rather than your new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error most likely indicates a Classpath issue where an old (very old pre 2018) proton-j library is being used. The method 'setOutboundFrameSizeLimit' was added many years ago to proton-j v0.27.0 and if not present in the version on the classpath it would throw an error.

Comment: There were some old proton jars as well in lib folder. I removed the old versions of jar and now getting "jakarta.jms.JMSException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException" at the same line. The code does work using a normal java application and simply using jakarta jms and qpid jms libraries

Comment: Technically speaking, this answer does address the question as it currently stands.

Comment: Sounds like I have answered the question, and now you should ask a new question with new debug details.

Comment: @TimBish The original issue is resolved. Thanks Tim and Justin. I am seeing a new error now, will create a new question for it.